# Probability of a die falling a six for the first time on the last throw

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Trying to do c),

So I know we want 1 success, but on the 4th trial. So k = 4, r = 1. And then I use the formula: $$\binom{k-1}{r-1} p^{r}q^{k-r}$$ and plug in:
$$\binom{3}{0} \bigg(\frac{1}{6}\bigg)^{1} \bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{3}$$

Is this correct?

EDIT: The formula I used is from this book:

[image]

Comment: What is the significance of the binomial coefficient?  We need the first three to b e non-sixes, so $\left( \frac 56\right)^3$, and then the last to be a six, so $\frac 16$.  Now just multiply.  Of course this comes to the same result, but I don't understand the general formula you use.

Comment: @lulu check the edit

Comment: This seems correct.

Comment: Ok, but it seems like overkill here.  We have a very precise situation...we want $XXX6$ where $X$ denotes anything other than a $6$.  The formula you cite concerns a situation in which other sixes will be scattered amongst the early throws, but your situation is much cleaner.  Nothing incorrect about it, just overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its correct, but can be solved with very simple solution - Probability it falls six for first time in last throw out of four throws

= Probability of not getting six in first three throws x Probability of getting six in last throw

$$= 5/6 \cdot  5/6 \cdot  5/6 \cdot  1/6$$

$$= \frac{125}{1296}$$

Even, going by book formula you are getting the same